# Centralise group titles of glossary

Tags: horizontal-alignment, glossaries, glossaries-extra

I have been using `glossaries-extra` to generate a list of symbols in my thesis but I have been struggling on the formatting side of things. More specifically, the problem is that my chapter titles are centred, but the glossary group titles are not.

I have had a look at the gallery for [Custom Group Blocks](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/gallery/index.php?label=logicaldivisions#customgroup) and also the different formatting `style`s, but I have not managed to find a solution. Ideally the list should look something like `style=long` (see Fig. below) but with group titles present, that are centred.

[image]

Is there a simple way to centre the group titles of a glossary?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[parskip,12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[record,symbols,nomain,stylemods={tree},shortcuts=other]{glossaries-extra}

\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}% Make chapters centred
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}% Roman fonts for Ch

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{bte}{Neutron transport}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{angdisc}{Angular discretisations}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newentry{r}{
  name={\ensuremath{\mathbf{r}}},
  description={Position},
  group={bte},
  type={symbols}
}
\newentry{S2}{
  name={\ensuremath{\mathit{S_2}}},
  description={Angular domain: the unit sphere},
  group={bte},
  type={symbols}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newentry{SN}{
  name={\ensuremath{S_N}},
  description={Discrete Ordinates discretisation of \gls{S2}},
  group={angdisc},
  type={symbols}
}
\newentry{PN}{
  name={\ensuremath{P_N}},
  description={Spherical Harmonics discretisation of \gls{S2}},
  group={angdisc},
  type={symbols}
}

% \printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=indexgroup,title={List of Symbols}]
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: The link you have posted is about customization with `bib2gls`, however, you are not using it. Have you tryed it with `bib2gls`?

Comment: @TomášKruliš I was under the impression that the majority of the settings for `glossaries-extra` were roughly the same regardless if you used `bib2gls` or pure LaTex, hence the link. To answer you question however, yes I did try it. The output looked identical to the MWE above, hence for the sake of simplicity I will refrain from using `bib2gls` in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having tested a few alternatives, including the answer posted by @Venez, I think the easiest solution to this question is to define a new glossary style based on `long`. The `long` style is effectively a `longtable` which means simple column manipulations can result to the style requested, i.e. centred group titles and glossary entries being placed toward the centre of the page.

Solution:

```
\documentclass[parskip,12pt,oneside,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[record,symbols,nomain,stylemods={tree},shortcuts=other]{glossaries-extra}% list of symbols

\renewcommand*{\raggedchapter}{\centering}% Make chapters centred
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily}% Roman fonts for Ch

\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{bte}{Neutron transport}
\glsxtrsetgrouptitle{angdisc}{Angular discretisations}

% Define a custom long style for groups; style=long uses longtables
\newglossarystyle{longgroup}{%
    \setglossarystyle{long}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    &%  Add empty column in longtable 
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{% Change the alignment just for the group title to centre
          \glsxtrgetgrouptitle{##1}{\glsxtrgrptitle}%
          % \glstreePreHeader{##1}{\glsxtrgrptitle}%
      \glstreegroupheaderfmt{\glsxtrgrptitle}%
    }%
    \cr% newline in table
    %\glsgroupskip% Uncomment for additional spacing below group title
    }%
}%

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newentry{r}{
  name={\ensuremath{\mathbf{r}}},
  description={Position},
  group={bte},
  type={symbols}
}
\newentry{S2}{
  name={\ensuremath{\mathit{S_2}}},
  description={Angular domain: the unit sphere},
  group={bte},
  type={symbols}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newentry{SN}{
  name={\ensuremath{S_N}},
  description={Discrete Ordinates discretisation of \gls{S2}},
  group={angdisc},
  type={symbols}
}
\newentry{PN}{
  name={\ensuremath{P_N}},
  description={Spherical Harmonics discretisation of \gls{S2}},
  group={angdisc},
  type={symbols}
}

% \printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=long,title={List of Symbols}]
\printunsrtglossary[type=symbols,style=longgroup,title={List of Symbols}]
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question you could simply renew the format by using

```
\renewcommand\glstreegroupheaderfmt[1]{\begin{center}\textbf{#1}\end{center}\vspace{-\parskip}}
```

and switching to the `alttreegroup` style. Therefore you must also use

```
\glsfindwidesttoplevelname
```

before the call of `\printunsrtglossary`. In the end it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, however, `alttreegroup` increases the spacing between the entries to what looks like double spacing and also places them at the leftmost border of the page. Do you know how to adjust the entry spacing and text justification to resemble more `style=long` but with groups?

Comment: Adding to my previous comment the entry spacing can be adjusted with something like this `\renewcommand{\glossarypreamble}{\glsfindwidesttoplevelname[\acronymtype] \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}` credit to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/391230/glossaries-style-index-spacing-between-gls-name-and-description)